# How to implement jms in jetspeed

Tags: jboss, queue, jms, jetspeed2

I need to send a message to jboss queue from a web application of jetspeed. I googled. ActiveMQ api is for jetspeed queue. But, I need to send a message to jboss queue where the message will be received by the listener in the jboss application. Is that possible to send a message through jetspeed to jboss queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone. I myself found the answer. In order to implement jms in jetspeed, I added some of the libraries from jboss such as Jbossall-client.jar,Jbossjmx-ant.jar,Jmx-client.jar and Jnp-client.jar to the jetspeed application. Then, it is working fine.